# Update average upon value push with mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have collection with a document structure that looks like this:

```
{
    id : 1,
    datasets : [
        {
            version : 1.1,
            data : [{x: 0, y: 1}, {x: 1, y: 2}],
            xAverage: 0.5,
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to make `xAverage` update every time a new point is added to the `data` array.

I am using `updateOne` for adding the new value like so:

```
collection.updateOne({id: req.params.id},
            { $addToSet: { "datasets.$[t].data":  req.body } },
            { arrayFilters: [ { "t.version": req.params.version } ], multi: true}, 
            function(err, result) {
              if (err) {
               res.send(err);
              } else {
                res.send(result);
              }
    });
```

but failed to understand how to update the average value accordingly. I tried combining `collection.aggregate()`.

What is the right way to update such object?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the nodejs-code you currently have for inserting?

Comment: @eol node.js code added

Answer (score 1):

Using `unwind` on the `dataset` and `data` arrays, allows you to calculate the average for the x-values:

```
db.getCollection('<your-collection>').aggregate([{
            "$unwind": {
                path: "$datasets"
            }
        }, {
            "$unwind": {
                path: "$datasets.data"
            }
        }, {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$id",
                "xAverage": {
                    "$avg": "$datasets.data.x"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

So for example if your collection contains the following two docs:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "datasets" : [ 
        {
            "version" : 1.1,
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "x" : 0.0,
                    "y" : 1.0
                }, 
                {
                    "x" : 1.0,
                    "y" : 2.0
                }, 
                {
                    "x" : 20.0,
                    "y" : 2.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id" : 2,
    "datasets" : [ 
        {
            "version" : 1.1,
            "data" : [ 
                {
                    "x" : 19.0,
                    "y" : 1.0
                }, 
                {
                    "x" : 1.0,
                    "y" : 2.0
                }, 
                {
                    "x" : 20.0,
                    "y" : 2.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

the aggregation above will return

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "xAverage" : 13.3333333333333
},
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "xAverage" : 7.0
}
```

If you really need to store the average along the inserted values, you can insert/append new data-points like you did, then calculate and get the average with the aggregation-query above and set the `xAverage` field with its result.